# R - Match based on minimum difference between column in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Subject=c("S1","S1","S2","S2","S2","S3","S3"), 
       SampleTime=c(1,2,1,2.1,3,0.9,2), Value=c(3,4,3,2,2,4,5))

df2 <- data.frame(Subject=c("S1","S1","S1","S2","S2","S2","S2","S3","S3"),
       SampleTime=c(0.99, 2.01,2.99, 0,1.01,2,3,1.2,2.02), Conc=c(4.7,5.2,8,5,2,1,3,4,6))
```

My goal is to add the column df2$Conc to df1 where the difference between SampleTime in df1 and df2 is smallest per subject. In addition, I would like to add a column that shows the difference between SampleTime.

Desired output:

```
output <- data.frame(Subject=c("S1","S1","S2","S2","S2","S3","S3"), 
                     SampleTime=c(1,2,1,2.1,3,0.9,2), Value=c(3,4,3,2,2,4,5), 
                     SampleTime_df2=c(0.99,2.01,1.01,2,3,1.20,2.02), Conc=c(4.7,5.2,2,1,3,4,6))
```

So far, I'm able to it per subject, like this for Subject S2:

```
     Indices <- sapply(df1$SampleTime[df1$Subject=="S2"], FUN=function(x,y) which.min(abs(y - x)), y=df2$SampleTime[df2$Subject=="S2"])
     df1$SampleTime_df2[df1$Subject=="S2"] <- df2$SampleTime[df2$Subject=="S2"][Indices]
     df1$Conc[df1$Subject=="S2"] <- df2$Conc[df2$Subject=="S2"][Indices]
```

The code doesn't look very nice and I would like to do it for all subjects at once. In my real data, there aren't any ties (i.e. two sample times in df2 that are equally closest to one sample time in df1), but let's say that in that case I would like to keep the first.

I hope my question is clear. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could use a cartesian join since it sounds like you might need to compare every combination of subject in df1 to subject in df2. However, these types are joins can get prohibitively large even for small datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for? Do an inner join, and then take the absolute difference, sort it and slice. This is all using dplyr

```
require(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>% 
         rename(ST1 = SampleTime) %>% 
         inner_join(df2, by = "Subject") %>%
         group_by(Subject, ST1) %>% 
         mutate(diff = abs(ST1 - SampleTime)) %>% 
         arrange(diff) %>% 
         slice(1) %>%
         ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Would it work in general to merge dataframes (inner join) on Subject and  new columns filled with round(SampleTime)? This approach would work with the toy data that you supplied, i.e.

```
df1$SampleTimeInt <- round(df1$SampleTime)
df2$SampleTimeInt <- round(df2$SampleTime)
combined <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("Subject", "SampleTimeInt"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see it works with the sample data, but ideally I would have a more generic solution, that also works if `round()` doesn't round to same number.